# How to Convert Python List with Bytes to Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The input is given as:
`rec = [b'1674278797,14.33681', b'1674278798,6.03617', b'1674278799,12.78418']`
I want to get a DataFrame like:

```
df
    timestamp       val
0  1674278797  14.33681
1  1674278798   6.03617
2  1674278799  12.78418
```

What is the most efficient way? Thanks!

If I can convert rec like
`[[1674278797,14.33681], [1674278798,6.03617], [1674278799,12.78418]]`
It would be easy for me by calling
`df = pd.DataFrame(rec, columns=['timestamp','val'])`
But I don't know how to do the conversion quickly.

btw, I got rec from a Redis list. I can modify the format of each element (for example, b'1674278797,14.33681' is an element) if necessory.

Comment: Where did this input come from? This looks like an attempt to read an ASCII string as raw bytes instead of a string. Or rather, the lines in a file as raw bytes, instead of a single string. It's *far* easier to let Pandas load the original data than try to make it work with the converted one. `pd.read_csv(the_original_file)` would just work

Comment: The data source is a recorder. It generates data 1~2 seconds per row. Only the recent 24 hours data is useful. There are several clients to access the data. So, I use Redis list to store the records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't directly handle the original input, you can use:

```
(pd.Series([x.decode('utf-8') for x in rec])
   .str.split(',', expand=True).convert_dtypes()
   .set_axis(['timestamp', 'val'], axis=1)
)
```

Or:

```
import io

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join([x.decode('utf-8') for x in rec])),
            header=None, names=['timestamp', 'val'])
```

Output:

```
    timestamp       val
0  1674278797  14.33681
1  1674278798   6.03617
2  1674278799  12.78418
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one line:

```
pd.DataFrame([x.decode().split(",") for x in rec], columns=["timestamp","val"])
```

Returns

```
    timestamp       val
0  1674278797  14.33681
1  1674278798   6.03617
2  1674278799  12.78418
```

If you want to convert the datatypes of the column you can add `.astype({"timestamp": "int64", "val": "float64"})` to the end of the line.

Comment: Very simple and clear. Thanks!